# Show that $89|(2^{44})-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that $89|(2^{44})-1$

My teacher proved this problem using mod can someone explain the process step by step? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 11):

We're interested in the remainder of $2^n$ upon division by $89$ for increasing values of $n$.  Here are the remainders for $n=1,2,\ldots,11$:

$$2,4,8,16,32,64,39,78,67,45,1$$

Notice that $2^{11}\equiv 1\pmod{89}$.  So that $2^{44}=(2^{11})^4\equiv\ldots$ (see if you can finish the argument).

Comment: Yes, I would simply note that this is the method that most computers use. Hence computing (100dig)^(10dig) mod (100dig) is easy for a computer, whereas something like (100dig)! mod (100dig) is not possible with modern technology.

Answer (score 7):

$$\begin{align}a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)\quad=>\quad2^{44}-1&=(2^{22}-1)(2^{22}+1)=\\&=\underbrace{(2^{11}-1)}_{2047{\large=}{\color{red}{89}}\cdot23}(2^{11}+1)(2^{22}+1).\end{align}$$

Answer (score 6):

One way is to note that because $89$ is a prime of the form $8k+1$, it follows that $2$ is a quadratic residue of $p$. Thus $x^2\equiv 2\pmod{89}$ for some $x$. It follows that
$$2^{44}\equiv (x^2)^{44}\equiv x^{88}\pmod{89}.$$

But $x^{88}\equiv 1\pmod{89}$ by Fermat's Theorem.

Comment: what does 2 is quadratic residue of p mean?

Comment: Oh my, the OP asks what a mod is and throw a quadratic residue??

Comment: @BobbyOcean:  I thought I recognized the name as that of someone who has asked number theory questions before.

Comment: Well in that case, I extend apologies. BTW, your argument is very unique and interesting. +1

Comment: No reason for apologies!  It is now clear that the argument I used is not well suited to the background of the OP.

Answer (score 1):

$2^{44} \mod{89} = 2^{32} \times 2^8 \times 2^4 \mod{89}$. Starting with $2^4 = 16 \mod{89}$, and doubling and taking mod, you get $16 \times 78 \times 45  = 1 \mod 89$ .Therefore $89$ divides $2^{44} - 1$.

Comment: ok after you convert 23^2×2^8×2^4 into mod how did you get that it equals 1(mod 89)?

Answer (score 0):

With a bit of calculation.

Need to prove $2^{44}\equiv 1\pmod{89}$.

$2^8=256=2\cdot 89+78=3\cdot 89-11$, so $2^8\equiv 78\equiv -11\pmod{89}$ $-$ it is a definition of $\pmod{}$ operation.
Then $2^3\cdot 2^8\equiv 8\cdot 2^8\equiv8\cdot 11\equiv-88 \equiv 1\pmod{89}$ $-$ because $1=1\cdot 89-88$.

So, you have $2^{11}\equiv 1\pmod{89}$ which means $2^{11}=k\cdot 89 +1$, where $k$ is an integer.
You can obtain from it that $(2^{11})^4=m\cdot 89 +1$, where $m$ will be another integer.