# Show that: $97\mid (2^{48})-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Verify $97\mid 2^{48}-1$

I am so confused with how mods worked. Can someone please work out this problem in the simplest terms possible? Thank you so much!

Comment: Your previous question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/726899/show-that-89244-1 got a lot of answers. Is there something you didn't understand about the methods given there?

Comment: I'm honestly so confused with all of the answers. Would you mind working this problem step by step so I can ask questions?

Comment: we can help you better if you tell us which parts are confusing you.

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of relevant theory that makes calculation unnecessary. But let us calculate, in an efficient way, using an ordinary calculator.

We have $2^6=64$. Now let us find the remainder when $2^{12}$, that is, $(2^6)^2$, is divided by $97$.

Square $64$ on the calculator. We get $4096$. Divide by $97$ on the calculator. Mine gives $42.22680412$. Subtract $42$ from this on the calculator, and multiply the result by $97$. We get $22$. On a different calculator, we might get a number very close to $22$, like $21.9999997$. We would still know the remainder is $22$.

So $2^{12}\equiv 22\pmod{97}$. Now find the remainder when $2^{24}$, that is, $(2^{12})^2$, is divided by $97$.

On the calculator, square $22$. Divide by $97$. We get something like $4.989690722$. On the calculator, subtract $4$, and multiply by $97$. We get $96$.
Thus $2^{24}\equiv 96\pmod{97}$.

Now we can either note that $96\equiv -1\pmod{97}$, and conclude that $2^{48}\equiv (-1)^2\equiv 1\pmod{97}$.

Or else we can blindly calculate. Square $96$, divide by $97$. We get $95.01030928$. Subtract $95$, multiply by $97$. We get $0.999999791$. The remainder is $1$.

Answer (score 2):

$\,\color{#c00}{2 = 14^{\large 2}} - 2(97),\,$ so $\, {\rm mod}\,\ 97\!:\ \color{#c00}{2\equiv 14^{\large 2}}\,\Rightarrow\,\color{#c00}2^{\large 48}\equiv (\color{#c00}{14^{\large 2}})^{\large 48}\equiv 14^{\large 96}\equiv 1\,$ by little Fermat. $ $ **QED**

Answer (score 1):

Without any of the relevant theory, like Andre's answer.

Using Difference of Two Squares factorization several times,

$2^{48} - 1 = (2^{24} + 1)(2^{12} + 1)(2^6 + 1)(2^3 + 1)(2^3 - 1)$

$97$ is prime, so it's clear $97$ doesn't divide any of the latter three factors (since $97$ is greater than them)

Furthermore, note that $2^{12} + 1 = 4097$, so it's easy to see that $97$ does not divide that either.

Thus, it must be the case that $97 \mid 2^{24} + 1$. Therefore, we wish to show that $2^{24} \equiv -1 \pmod {97}$

Through brute force, we find that $2^{12} \equiv 22 \pmod {97}$. Brute forcing again, $(2^{12})^2 = 2^{24} \equiv 22^2 \equiv -1 \pmod {97}$, as desired.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Since $97$ is prime, by Fermat's little theorem it follows that
$$2^{96} \equiv 1 \pmod{97}$$
Now notice that $48 \times 2 = 96$ and take it from there.

*Side note: I'm reluctant to give a full worked solution to this problem. If you're still stuck, feel free to ask questions and I'll be happy to help out.*

Comment: ok can you just walk me through this, 
 So initially I was thinking of having 2^48≡1(mod 97) then I was going to break up 2^48 into something smaller. Is this correct?

Comment: ok, does this approach work: 
97|2^48-1
2^16x2^16x2^8x2^8=2^48(mod 97)
2^32≡61(mod 97)
2^8≡62(mod 97)

Comment: @Clive No, it *is* true that $\,2^{48}\equiv 1\pmod{97}.\,$ There are *two*, not *one*, square roots of $1,\,$ viz $\,\pm1.\ \ $

Comment: @Clive but a^2 congruent to b^2 need not imply that a is congruent to b

Answer (score -2):

(2^3-1)(2^3+1)(2^6+1)(2^12+1)(2^24+1)(2^48+1)
now take (2^3-1)(2^3-1)=(8-1)(8+1)=7*9=63
now take (2^6+1)=64
(2^12+1)=4097
(2^24+1)=16777216+1=16777217
that is divisible by 97
we can break the whole set of things into 6 parts and can try them to prove.this is lengthy method but as the question have a²-b² formula i think it will have to work